# Twitter REST API を用いてRTのRTをした流れを取得

Tags: twitter

仮定：
・ユーザA
・ユーザAのフォロワーにユーザB
・ユーザBのフォロワーにユーザC

ユーザAがツイートしたとき，そのツイートをユーザBがRT（リツイート）して，さらにそのツイートをユーザCがRTしたとき，この流れをTwitter REST API を利用して取得する方法はありますか？

つまり，以下のような波及する様子を取得したいです．
ツイート -> ユーザBがRT -> ユーザCがRT

Answer (score 1):

現実的では無いかも知れませんが、可能かも知れません。
RTは"RT @id"という文字列で始まる別のツイートIDで管理されます。

1. `statuses/retweets/:id`にオリジナルのツイートのIDを指定してレスポンスを取得
2. 1で取得したレスポンスの各RTのIDを`statuses/retweets/:id`に設定して再びRTを取得

これを繰り返せば取れるだろうと思います。
ただし`statuses/retweets/:id`は15回/15分しか使えませんし、一度に100ツイートしか取得できないので、取得できる限界は15回RTされたところまで、また一度に100RT分の所在しか分かりません。これ以上取得するには15分ごとに時間を空けるしかなさそうです。